# gcc g++ - configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to compile and build libsigc++-2.10.2 on cygwin with gcc 8.3.0.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

when I run ./configure, I get this:

```
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features by default... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -std=c++11... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with +std=c++11... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -h std=c++11... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -std=c++0x... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with +std=c++0x... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -h std=c++0x... no
configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required.
```

IF I try to run autogen.sh then it throws:

```
configure.ac:28: installing 'build/missing'
Makefile.am:20: error: ENABLE_DOCUMENTATION does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
build/doc-reference.am:64: error: DIST_DOCTOOLS does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
docs/Makefile.am:32:   'build/doc-reference.am' included from here
build/doc-reference.am:70: error: ENABLE_DOCUMENTATION does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
docs/Makefile.am:32:   'build/doc-reference.am' included from here
examples/Makefile.am: installing 'build/depcomp'
autoreconf-2.69: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

Please advise, thanks!!

Comment: There are probably better ways of resolving this, but check how configure is checking for C++ 11 support. The `configure.log` should tell you.

Comment: I couldn't fully understand what does configure.log says here but it seems compiler admits that it is not ready for C++11? i copied entire log to https://pastebin.com/x083cQLD

Please advise, thanks